# How to detect if Angular 2 component has attribute

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I have an Angular 2 component that looks like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-message',
  template: `
    <p *ngIf="messageWasSet">{{message}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="!messageWasSet">No message was specified</p>
  `
})
export class MessageComponent {
  @Input() public message: string;

  public messageWasSet: boolean; // How to calculate this?
}
```

Here are some example usages:

**Example 1**

```
<my-message message="Hi world"></my-message>

<!-- Rendered innerHTML -->
<p>Hi world</p>
```

**Example 2**

```
<!-- suppose obj.message = 'Viva Angular 2!' -->
<my-message [message]="obj.message"></my-message>

<!-- Rendered innerHTML -->
<p>Viva Angular 2!</p>
```

**Example 3**

```
<!-- suppose obj.message = undefined -->
<my-message [message]="obj.message"></my-message>

<!-- Rendered innerHTML -->
<p></p>
```

**Example 4**

```
<!-- Notice that there is no `message` binding at all -->
<my-message></my-message>

<!-- Rendered innerHTML -->
<p>No message was specified</p>
```

My question is how can I calculate the `messageWasSet` boolean property **without using `ElementRef`**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-message',
  template: `
    <p *ngIf="messageWasSet">{{message}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="!messageWasSet">No message was specified</p>
  `
})
export class MessageComponent {
  private _message: string;      

  public get message() {
    return this._message;
  }

  @Input() public set message(value: string) {
    this.messageWasSet = true;
    this._message = value;
  }

  public messageWasSet: boolean; // How to calculate this?
}
```

Comment: I want to programmatically compute `messageWasSet` based on whether or not the `message="..."` attribute exists on the component. Consumers of the component don't set `messageWasSet`, it's computed automatically.
Basically, I want to distinguish between the fact that the `message` is `undefined` because it was never set vs it's `undefined` because it was set to `undefined`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your answer is very close. It just needs to handle the fact that even if `value` is undefined, I still want `messageWasSet` to be true.

And just for completeness, will you add a getter for the `message` (making sure to save the `value` to some private property)?

Comment: I updated my answer again. If this doesn't work you'll probably need to use `elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute()`, `getAttribute()` won't recognize `[message]="obj.message"` though because attribute bindings are never added to the DOM. You might be able to use a combination of these methods though to cover all cases.

Comment: This works! I edited your answer to include a getter for the `message` just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

you may create `messageWasSet` as a property which returns value based upon `message` like below,

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3>How to detect if Angular 2 component has attribute</h3>
  <hr />
  Child component
  <my-message [message]="obj.message" ></my-message>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  obj = { message: 'hello' };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-message',
  template: `
    <p *ngIf="messageWasSet">{{message}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="!messageWasSet">No message was specified</p>
  `
})
export class MessageComponent {
  @Input() public message: string;

  get messageWasSet(){
    return !!this.message;
  }
}
```

Here is [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/w4VOzH3xdN2ieVnNixab?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!